# LINQ generate entity without my consent

Tags: c#, xml, linq, wix

I have this code C# to create XElement :

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";
XElement elem = new XElement (ns + "CustomAction", new Object[] {
                                new XAttribute("Id", "shellex"), new XAttribute("Directory", "WINDOWSVOLUME"), new XAttribute("Impersonate", "no"), 
                                new XAttribute("ExeCommand", @"cmd.exe /c move &quot;C:\Documents and Settings\test.txt&quot; &quot;C:\&quot; "), 
                                new XAttribute("Return", "asyncNoWait")});
```

And i have a function wich add this XElement on a specific node into XML file.

So, the program generates this line on my XML file :

```
<CustomAction Id="shellex" Directory="WINDOWSVOLUME" Impersonate="no" 
ExeCommand="cmd.exe /c move &amp;quot;C:\Documents and Settings\test.txt&amp;quot; &amp;quot;C:\&amp;quot; " Return="asyncNoWait" />
```

LINQ generates `&amp;` entity before `&quot;` and with this my ExeCommand doesn't work.

But i don't understand why LINQ generates this.
How to cancel the generation of `&amp;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your quotations and there are two ways of doing this:

Using backslashes in a regular string:

```
\"
```

Using double quotation marks in a @-delimited string:

```
""
```

This should work:

```
new XAttribute("ExeCommand", @"cmd.exe /c move ""C:\Documents and Settings\test.txt"" ""C:\""; "),
```

Comment: Ok it works, thanks. But i always don't understand ... &amp; escape quot but why it don't work then ?

Comment: `&quot;` escapes an `#` in xml, not in C#.